# coffeescript/node: undefined var but unsure why

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have those lines of code in coffeescript:

```
  useragent = if req and req.headers then req.headers['user-agent'] else ""
  isIE = ~useragent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie')
```

however this code started throwing errors out of nowhere after running for several months:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

any clue about what might be wrong?

Comment: The first thing I would do is look at the generated JavaScript from your actual CoffeeScript file (not just the code copied and pasted). Indentation is a bit^H^H^H problematic thing with CoffeeScript, so it's important to see how the actual file itself is being transpiled.

Comment: You're not checking if `req.headers['user-agent']` is defined, so it could be undefined or not a string, which would cause this.

Comment: You are basically doing `useragent = req?.headers?['user-agent'] ? ''`

Comment: @plalx: `~-1===0==false`.

Comment: @plalx bitwise NOT is a nice way to coerce the return value of `indexOf` to false if it didn't find the substring, true if it did.

Comment: Which is basically `isIE = 'msie' in useragent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.headers['user-agent']` could be undefined as well. Try the following:

```
useragent = req?.headers?['user-agent'] ? ''
isIE = 'msie' in useragent.toLowerCase()
```

It assumes user-agent if found will always be a string. Otherwise you'd want to check for the type explicitly.